# How to use a variable in a curl URL in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to use curl with a URL containing two dates. How can I use the values of two variables containing date/time stamps instead of hard coded dates in the URL? I want to use a range from 50 minutes ago to the current time.

Here is my code with hard coded date/time values:

```
#!/bin/bash

currentTime=$(date +"%R")
currentdate=$(date +'%m/%d/%Y')
oldtime=$(date +%R -d "50 min ago")

echo "Current time : $currentTime"
echo "Current Date : $currentdate"
echo "Old time : $oldtime"

Response=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Token=" "http://targetserver.companyname.com:8080/v1/organizations/companyname/environments/environmentname/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange=01/24/2017%2002:00~01/25/2017%2006:00")
```

I tried replacing the hard coded dates as follows, but it didn't work:

```
Response=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Token=" "http://targetserver.company.com:8080/v1/organizations/company/environments/environmentname/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange="$currentdate" "$currentTime"~"$currentdate" "$oldtime"")
```

Comment: Could you show at least *one* way you tried? Also, what does this have to do with `r`?

Comment: You know how to use a variable in a string - you have used in `echo` statements. You can use the same mechanism in the `curl` statement.

Comment: Hi chepner ... please see below the way I was trying ...
Response=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Token=" "http://targetserver.companyname.com:8080/v1/organizations/companyname/environments/environmentname/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange=01/24/2017%2002:00~01/25/2017%2006:00")
echo -e "The response is :\n $Response"
value=$(Response|jsawk 'return this.values')
echo "the value is : $value"

The error is "command not found"
I am using cygwin, and tried downloading different js package but still not working.

Comment: Response=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Token=" "http://targetserver.company.com:8080/v1/organizations/company/environments/environmentname/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange="$currentdate"%20"$currentTime"~"$currentdate"%20"$oldtime"")
echo -e "the response is: \n $Response"
Tried but did not work.

Comment: Hi Chepner please see the below command. It's not working though.
Response=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Token=" "http://targetserver.company.com:8080/v1/organizations/company/environments/environmentname/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange="$currentdate"%20"$currentTime"~"$currentdate"%20"$oldtime"")
echo -e "the response is: \n $Response"

Comment: I'v edited your question by reformulating it and adding information that was in the comments, namely what you tried to replace the variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
Response=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Token=" "http://targetserver.company.com:8080/v1/organizations/company/environments/environmentname/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange=${currentdate}%20${currentTime}~${currentdate}%20${oldtime}")
```

I made a working example, here:

```
#!/bin/bash
example="Just_A_Test_String"
response=$(curl -X GET "http://5.135.224.191/test_curl.php?var1=${example}")
echo $response
```

Comment: `echo "$response"` would be a bit less buggy with the double quotes; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Completely agree @CharlesDuffy - I normally do that, however slipped my mind at the time.