# How to use current date in a curl command in shell script?

Tags: shell, curl

```
#!/bin/bash
currentTime=$(date +"%R")
currentdate=$(date +'%m/%d/%Y')
oldtime=$(date +%R -d "50 min ago")
echo "Current time : $currentTime"
echo "Current Date : $currentdate"
echo "Old time : $oldtime"
Response=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Token=" "http://targetserver.company.com:8080/v1/organizations/company/environments/environmentname/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange="$currentdate"%20"$currentTime"~"$currentdate"%20"$oldtime"")
echo -e "the response is: \n $Response"
```

Not getting any response? Please help how to use system date-time/current date-time in curl URL in shell-script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable in a curl URL in shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875493/how-to-use-a-variable-in-a-curl-url-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

it looks consistent, but not entirely sure what looks wrong.  have you tried to `echo` the Response line to see what it looks like?  how about trying it with wrapping the bash variable names in curly brace and removing the quotes in the string?

`Response=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Token=" "http://targetserver.company.com:8080/v1/organizations/company/environments/environmentname/stats/apis?select=sum(is_error)&timeRange=${currentdate}%20${currentTime}~${currentdate}%20${oldtime}")`